# SemanticUI Dropdown form not sent

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dropdown

I got following piece of code (shortened for this question purpose)

```js
    $(function() {
  var professions = [{"name":"Altenpflegehelfer","value":"3"},{"name":"Altenpfleger","value":"4"},{"name":"Änderungsschneider","value":"2"},{"name":"Anlagenmechaniker","value":"5"},{"name":"Anlagenmechaniker für Sanitär-, Heizungs- und Klimatechnik (früher: Zentralheizungs- und Lüftungsbauer)","value":"6"},{"name":"Asphaltbauer","value":"7"}];
  
        $('#profession').dropdown({
            values: professions,
            fullTextSearch: true,
        });

    });
```

```html
<head>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Semantic UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css"  />
</head>
<body>
<form class="ui large form" action="post.php" method="post">
 <div class="one field">
  <label for="profession">Profession</label>
  <select name="profession" class="ui search dropdown" id="profession"></select>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>

</script>
</body>
```

The problem is, when i send the form, the $_REQUEST variable from PHP is empty.

You can simply test it by creating new file post.php with this content:

```
<?php echo var_dump($_REQUEST); ?>
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var professions = [{"name":"Altenpflegehelfer","value":"3"},{"name":"Altenpfleger","value":"4"},{"name":"Änderungsschneider","value":"2"},{"name":"Anlagenmechaniker","value":"5"},{"name":"Anlagenmechaniker für Sanitär-, Heizungs- und Klimatechnik (früher: Zentralheizungs- und Lüftungsbauer)","value":"6"},{"name":"Asphaltbauer","value":"7"}];
  
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown({
   placeholder: "Search your profession",
            values: professions,
            fullTextSearch: true,
        });
  
    });
```

```html
<head>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Semantic UI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.14/semantic.min.css"  />
</head>
<body>
<form class="ui large form" action="post.php" method="post">
 <div class="field"> <!--  creating a field -->
  <label>Profession</label>
  <div class="ui search labeled selection dropdown">
   <input name="profession" type="hidden"> <!-- store the selected value that gonna be posted -->
   <span class="text"></span>
   <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)